# vim: autoindent not working

Tags: vim, vi

my autoindent is not working, any diagnostic tests to figure it out?

my ":set" is:

> :set
>   --- Options ---   cindent             laststatus=2        scroll=17
>   tabstop=4           window=36
>   filetype=cpp        number
>   smartindent         ttyfast
>   helplang=en         paste
>   syntax=cpp          ttymouse=xterm2
>   backspace=indent,eol,start
>   fileencoding=utf-8
>   fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
>   printoptions=paper:letter
>   runtimepath=~/.vim,/var/lib/vim/addons,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim72,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/af
>   ter,/var/lib/vim/addons/after,~/.vim/after
>   suffixes=.bak,~,.swp,.o,.info,.aux,.log,.dvi,.bbl,.blg,.brf,.cb,.ind,.idx,.ilg,.inx,.out,.toc

Comment: i noticed i have to type :set autoindent manually for it to work. im wondering howcome its not automatically included since it is in my .vimrc

Comment: is there no accepted answer for this question?

Comment: notice: autoindent does not work in paste mode, try `set nopaste`

Answer (score 14):

try:

```
:set ai
```

or:

```
:set autoindent
```

find more about auto-indent:

```
:h ai
```

Otherwise, it's might be something with file type detection.

Comment: This worked for me for `.tex` files. Maybe in combination with the answer by @benoit (Which did not work at first)

Answer (score 12):

In case someone else face the same issue, I had a similar issue that none of the above fixed. 
What was wrong for me was the tab interpretations. here is the set up that made it work:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
set smartindent
```

And to check when indenting if the indentation was correct, I added the following, still in my vimrc file:

```
" helper for indent mistake
set list listchars=tab:»·,trail:·
```

Which display a "»" instead of the regular "·" if my indent is wrong. Very handy.
Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked for me also, but I removed the tabstop setting and changed the shiftwidth to 4 instead of 2 and that worked for me

Answer (score 12):

I had a stale function in `indentexpr` which persisted after changing the filetype. This eventually fixed it for me:

```
:set indentexpr=
```

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and these settings fixed it.

```
filetype on
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

Comment: I added a single line for this to my ~/.vimrc:
`filetype plugin indent on`

Answer (score 7):

You should probably turn off `smartindent` and use `:filetype indent on` and `cindent` (which seems to be also set) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to test out whether you have the configuration correct, then persist your configuration so Vim always operates thusly. `This font` indicates text which should be typed in literally, except `<CR>` means press the "Enter" or "Return" key.

- Create a new system user, with a new home directory.
- Start Vim. All settings should be set however they ship with Vim by default.
- Open a file, say, test.txt.
- Make sure autoindent is enabled (`:set ai?<CR>`)
- Prove that autoindent doesn't happen:

  - Type a space or two, then hit enter.
  - When the cursor advances to the next line, it should return to column 1, the far-left column.
- Turn on autoindent (`:set ai<CR>`)
- Make sure autoindent is enabled (`:set ai?<CR>`)
- Prove that autoindent happens:

  - Type a space or two, then hit enter.
  - When the cursor advances to the next line, it should still be in the same column.
- Persist autoindent with `:mkvimrc<CR>`.

Hope that helps! Here are some other notes:

- These instructions might be specific to left-to-right locales.
- [Here's my vimrc](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZLHK83ucXAEJ%3adotfiles.org/~meonkeys/.vimrc+meonkeys+vimrc&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

"The 'autoindent' option is reset when the 'paste' option is set". So try to remove 'paste' from your settings ([vim-options](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html)).

Answer (score 1):

`:set smartindent?` showd: `nosmartindent`

Then activating it with `:set smartindent` solved problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I have tried many commands, all failed.
At last, I use the following command, and it works:
`autocmd VimEnter * set autoindent`
It's not a elegant method, however, it does works.